# Loop through objects to find a match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, rails-activerecord

I have a `Shift` and a `Type` table with the following relations:

```
class Shift < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :type
end

class Type < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shifts, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

The `Type` table has a attribute called `Unassignable`.

I would like to do a query which returns all the `Shifts` which belongs to a `Type` where the `Unassignable` attribute is `true`..

Something like:
Shift.where(:shift.type.unassignable => true)

Any help :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Shift.includes(:type).where("types.unassignable = ?", true)
```

Comment: simple, but just the one I needed :)